# Using tablesorter to sort two codependent table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am trying to build a table that has two codependent columns.  The behavior I am trying to achieve is, if column 1 or 2 is sorted, whether in ascending or descending order, the other column is sorted in descending order.  The column that is not being sorted needs to maintain descending order.  The table can contain duplicate entries in either column.  I have read about sortForce as an option to force column 1 to sort based off of column 2, but I have not found a way to make both column 1 and column 2 behave identically in reference to the other column's state.  How can this be achieved?

I currently have the following configuration.

```
$(function () {
  $('table').tablesorter({
    ignoreCase: true,
    sortList: [ [0,0], [1,0] ],
    sortAppend: {
        1 : [[ 2, 'd' ]], // always apply descending sort
        2 : [[ 1, 'd' ]]
    },
    sortInitialOrder: "desc",
    sortRestart: true
  });
});
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1/th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


Following the table below, lets say I click to sort column 1 in descending order.  Then I would like for the columns to be ordered as:
C : A
C : B
B : A
A : B

If I click on column 1 again to get a ascending order, I would like column 2 to maintain its descending order based off of column 1.
A : B
B : A
C : A
C : B

If I click on column 2 to sort descending, I would like the inverse behavior.  
A : B
C : B
B : A
C : A

And in the last case, if I click to have column 2 in ascending order, it would read as.
B : A
C : A
A : B
C : B
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`sortAppend` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortappend). Instead of setting it with an array of values, set it as an object containing the column key (index or selector) and the sort to append.

In this case, I believe the following settings will fulfill your needs:

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        ignoreCase: true,
        sortList: [ [0,0], [1,0] ],
        sortAppend: {
            1 : [[ 2, 'd' ]], // always apply descending sort
            2 : [[ 1, 'd' ]]
        },
        sortInitialOrder: "desc",
        sortRestart: true
    });
});
```

* Note: The sort direction can be set using `a` (ascending), `d` (descending), `n` (next), `s` (same) & `o` (opposite):

Comment: Oops, [here's a demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-append.html)

Comment: I'm running the code.  This looks like the solution I was searching for, but the table is getting into a strange state when I try to sort it.  After clicking on either column header, both end up with a class of 'tablesorter-headerUnSorted', causing the table to freeze up.

Comment: Please modify the demo so I can see the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Mottie.  I have updated the code.  I am using exactly what you'd suggested.